# Visualforce Email Autoreply PDF Template concept (PDF with page quantity based on value)

Tags: visualforce, email, pdf

This may not be possible, but I am wondering if there is a way to generate multiple PDF pages within a PDF based on the copies an contact requests when filling out an online form. It's like this.

1) A user in a form specifies that they are purchasing X tickets for an event, if the user wants just 1 ticket, then the attached PDF from the visualforce autoreply will generate a PDF with just one page only. If the user wants 2 tickets, then 2 pages and so on and so forth, with the page number specified somewhere in the template.

Let me know if this is achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible and can be fairly easily done. Implementation would depend largely on the page design for the "ticket", but mostly involves using the "ticket count" as an `<apex: repeat>` on the visualforce page and also in the footer or header for the page count which is sent to the page from the controller.

As a very simplified example, if you had a page that consisted of a table with your ticket inside it, you'd set it up something like this:

```
<apex: page  controller='mycustomcontroller' renderas='pdf'>
<html>
<apex: repeat>
<table>

//.... page content for ticket 

<table footer> 
// content with pagecount variable
</table footer>
</table>
</apex: repeat>
</html>
</apex: page>
```

In your CSS for the page, you'd also include CSS for the Table that has 
`style="page-break-after: always;"`

Another way of adding the page number to the page itself, instead of to the footer of the table, is to do something like this in your CSS instead:

```
@page {
   size: 8.5in 11in;
   margin: 10%;
   @top-right {
   content: "Page " counter(page);
   }
}
```

These things need to be passed to your page from the controller.